# How do I get CListCtrl to span small icons horizontally?

Tags: mfc

I'm trying to get a CListCtrl to show me a bunch of small icons going horizontally, but I can't seem to figure out what settings would do this.  How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it in dialog editor, view=small icon, or

```
dwStyle |= LVS_SMALLICON
mlistctrl.Create( dwStyle, rect, parent, id );

//or
mlistctrl.ModifyStyle(LVS_REPORT, LVS_SMALLICON);
```

Comment: I had tried that already.  After a lot of experimentation, I found out it was how I was adding the Image List.  I was using `LVSIL_SMALL` instead of `LVSIL_NORMAL` for  the 2nd parameter of `CListCtrl::SetImageList(CImageList*, int)`.  I'll give this to you anyway.

Comment: I knew that was too simple to be the answer. Thanks for giving me point on technical merits.